# owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, class, state

## There is no problem with the codes but when I run

I get error **owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this is not true** how can i solve this problem

```
class HomePage  extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();

  @override
  dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
}

class HomePageState extends State{

  late int first, second;
  late String islem;
  late String result, sonuc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `StatefulWidget` format, try

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late int first, second;
  late String islem;
  late String result, sonuc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    first = 1;
    second = 2;
    islem = "islem";
    result = "A";
    sonuc = "sonuc";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest
I did what you said and got this error;

No such method error build method not found
Receiver Instance of "_HomePageState"
Arguments:[Instance of 'StatefulElement']

Comment: you will get a build method inside `_HomePageState` class